# Linq: Count value of multiple column

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a table like below:

[image]

Now I want a result like 
[image]

In a single query how is it possible to prepare an entity like below?

```
public BurndownJiraIssue(
            DateTime date,
            int toDoCount,
            int inProgressCount)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can GroupBy Date to get the required reuslt

```
    var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => new BurndownJiraIssue
    {
        Date = x.Key,
        ToDoCount = x.ToList().Count(c => c.Status == "In Progress"),
        InProgressCount = x.ToList().Count(c => c.Status == "Done"),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__) of `.GroupBy`:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<StatusDTO> statuses = new List<StatusDTO>
        {
            new StatusDTO
            {
                Id = 1,
                Date = "8-Apr",
                Status = "In Progress"
            },
            new StatusDTO
            {
                Id = 2,
                Date = "8-Apr",
                Status = "In Progress"
            },
            new StatusDTO
            {
                Id = 3,
                Date = "8-Apr",
                Status = "In Progress"
            },
            new StatusDTO
            {
                Id = 4,
                Date = "8-Apr",
                Status = "Done"
            },
            new StatusDTO
            {
                Id = 5,
                Date = "9-Apr",
                Status = "In Progress"
            },
            new StatusDTO
            {
                Id = 6,
                Date = "9-Apr",
                Status = "Done"
            },
            new StatusDTO
            {
                Id = 7,
                Date = "9-Apr",
                Status = "Done"
            }
        };

        List<ResultStatusDTO> results = statuses.GroupBy(x => x.Date, x => x, (a, b) => new ResultStatusDTO
        {
            Date = a,
            DoneCount = b.Count(x => x.Status == "Done"),
            InProgressCount = b.Count(x => x.Status == "In Progress")
        }).ToList();

    }
}

public class ResultStatusDTO
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int InProgressCount { get; set; }
    public int DoneCount { get; set; }
}

public class StatusDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```